# Relativity between rank, m, n in $m \times n$ matrix $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra

1.For a system $Ax=b$ to have unique solution for some $b \in {\rm I\!R}^m$, and for others wont have solution.

- for no solutions it will be $rank(A)<m=n$ (1)
- for unique solutions it will be $rank(A)=m=n$ (2)

and because we want them both we will have $rank(A)≤m=n$

please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: We write $Ax=b$, with no times sign, and if you really must then write “\times” in the MathJax

Answer (score 1):

The general result is the following:

> A linear system $Ax=b$ has solutions if & only if the matrix $A$ and the augmented matrix $[A\,b]$ have the same rank. If it is the case, this common rank is the *codimension* of the set of solutions (as an affine subspace).